# Are ideal op-amp characteristics redundant for solving ideal op-amp circuits?

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

I have found that for solving problems with ideal op-amps, you need two rules:

1. The potential at A is the same as that at B
2. No current flows into or out of A or B

I have also come across a third rule:

3. No current flows into or out of C

I know this obviously not how an op-amp works in reality, and I have found that it is a redundant rule (i.e. all problems can be solved without considering it), but so far I  have not found an ideal op-amp circuit where this rule cannot be true. That is, I haven't found a circuit where the consideration of this rule changes the answer that you get.

My question is: can you find a circuit where this rule physically *cannot* be true?

Comment: @JThistle:  Your "third rule" can't be redundant because it isn't one of the rules for ideal op-amps in negative feedback.  It is just "wrong."

Comment: I'd be interested to hear where the OP got that 3rd rule from. It's self-evidently wrong to anyone who's ever used or designed an op-amp circuit. I suspect you made it up in order to concoct this ridiculous question. This is not 'electronics golf' you know...

Comment: @SimonTillson disregarding your frankly offensive manner; this is a genuine question I had based on the way that a tutor of mine solved a specific set of op-amp questions. He decided that he didn't want to learn how op-amps worked, so he reverse engineered the solution methods from the provided solutions, and ended up with these three rules. Obviously in lectures, we were only taught the first two (and, we were also taught how op-amps actually work, so I'm painfully aware that the third rule makes no physical sense). I am simply trying to find a situation which proves this rule of his wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your 3rd rule

> 3. No current flows into or out of C

is definitely wrong. It is quite the opposite of one
of the definitions of an ideal op-amp.

Quoted from [Electronics tutorials - Operational Amplifier Basics - Op-amp Parameter and Idealised Characteristic](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_1.html):

> - **Output impedance, (\$Z_\text{out}\$)**
>
> **Zero** – The output impedance of the ideal operational amplifier is  assumed to be zero acting as a perfect internal voltage source with no internal resistance so that it can supply as much current as necessary to the load.

Consider for example this simple voltage follower circuit
driving a light bulb as the output load.

[image]

The input voltage \$V_B\$ is 5 volt, hence (from your rule 1) also input voltage \$V_A\$ and output voltage \$V_C\$ is 5 volt, and the output current is whatever current the light bulb draws at 5 volts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why is it the case that the light bulb must draw a current? Is the only answer to that question, "because it's how op-amps work"?

Comment: No, because that's how light bulbs work. When voltage is applied to a light bulb, it will draw current and light up. Unless the bulb is burned out.

Comment: @JThistle I'm a bit puzzled that you are a physics student and don't even know how a light bulb works. Buy one! It has some metal conductor inside. You can measure its resistance with a multimeter. Do it! The rest is Ohm's law: you apply a voltage on a resistor and it draws current. U=R x I. The power P=U x I will heat that metal thing up until it starts glowing.

Comment: @ThomasWeller yeah sorry, I realise that was a stupid question. I do own lightbulbs! I have measured these exact quantities with multimeters (in early secondary school, no less)! This whole debacle clouded my thinking a bit in regards to this :)  --- I think my line of reasoning was that it is possible to have a potential difference without current, although obviously not across an Ohmic component, lol

Comment: @Justme currently kicking myself for saying such a stupid thing, apologies

Answer (score 7):

You should add a rule before rule 1:

- The opamp is used in a **circuit** with **negative** feedback.

You can't use an opamp on its own, it needs to be **part of a circuit**.

Your rule 1 only applies to opamps used in a circuit with [negative feedback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_feedback). In circuits with **[positive feedback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_feedback)** (example: the [Schmitt trigger circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmitt_trigger)) rule 1 does not apply.

Rule 2 is usually true "in first order" meaning, we're not considering details. However in reality depending on model of the opamp, a **small current** (less than 1 uA for example) can flow into (or out of) the inputs. That can have an influence on the rest of the circuit which sometimes needs to be taken into account.

As mentioned in the other answer, rule 3 is nonsense. In some circuits it is possible that the output current of the opamp is zero but that is not a general truth. Quite the opposite, the output current is generally not zero.

Comment: _rule 1 does not apply [to a Schmitt trigger]_ - this surprises me? Input equivalence is used to analyse the start of both hysteresis transition points.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: can you find a circuit where this rule physically cannot be true?

Problem: Consider the below op-amp circuit, with feedback resistance Rf=10k and R2=1k and input voltage is -1 volt. What will output voltage, considering this op-amp as:

i) ideal
ii) non-ideal (open loop Gain is 10^5)

[image]

Solution:

Considering it as ideal where you consider open loop gain as infinite:

Vout = -(Rf/R2) x Vin = **10 volt**

Considering it as non-ideal:

[image]

After putting values in this formula u get Vout = **9.998 Volt**

In the real scenarios, we can not apply ideal characteristics,but you can see the effect when we do not apply ideal characteristics.  The output voltages differ by 0.002 volt, which is very little.